# Trying to change the Ruff default line length

Tags: python-3.x, lint, ruff

I was recently introduced to Ruff a python linter. I have an existing directory with lots of files. I thought to try it out and made a pyproject.toml file in the directory. I want to set the line-length high (150) to show less errors but the default (88) keeps appearing. I also tried the ignore option but that does not seem to work either. Do I need to type a command to initiate the use of the pyproject.toml?

code from pyproject.toml

```
[tool.ruff]
extend-select = ["C4", "NPY", "PD", "SIM", "TCH"]
ignore = ["E501"]
show-fixes = true
# target-version = "py310"

# change the default line length number or characters.
line-length = 150
```

Another option is to have the linter ignore line lengths.

Comment: We have the same sort of file which works fine. Only thing I can think of is that the pyproject.toml is not in the correct place. But that's hard to determine from your question. If you run `ruff check -v .` it will output something like `[2023-09-26][14:21:16][ruff_cli::resolve][DEBUG] Using pyproject.toml (parent) at /home/uittenbroek/projects/myproject/pyproject.toml`

Comment: Have you tried putting the `line-length = 150` at the top rather than at the bottom?


[tool.ruff]
line-length = 150
indent-width = 4

[tool.ruff.lint]
select = ["C","E","F","W"]
ignore = ["E501"]